# Run Activity Indicator across Views

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner/

To show an acitvity indicator, its very easy:

```
SwiftSpinner.show("Loading Data")
```

However, I have a view that I am getting to from:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewC1Segue", sender: self)
```

when clicked on a table view cell.

The problem is, when i go to this new view, there is an initial blank white screen because the data is loaded via alamofire and takes a few moments to load.

Is there a way to load the activity spinner on one view, and let the views change undeneath it, then when I use the .hide() on the new view the spinner will disappear?

There is also another Dilemma:

I have tried adding that swift spinner onto the new viewDidLoad. It works, however, most of the content is loaded under the ViewDidAppear function. As soon as I add this function, The spinner fails to load.

Ok, so I have another question:

What would be the best way to not show the blank view at the beginning until the data loads?

Comment: Load the data before you present the next view controller.

Comment: The next view controller loads the data depending on what is passed, would I load the JSON in the performForSegue ??

Comment: Before you being the segue, you need to load whatever you're presenting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The user clicks a cell in a table, that goes to the new view, depending on the cell clicked the view gets the data. At which  point do I load the data? on the cell click? perform segue? I can't load all the data for all the cells in the table as there are hundreds

Comment: 1. User takes an interaction which allows you to know you will have to load a lot of data.  2. Present some sort of loading indicator. 3. Load the data. 4. Segue to the next view controller. 5. Present the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the spinner over several views, you could create a new LoadingViewController and a nib for it, set it's `backgroundColor` to transparent, show the LoadingViewController over the current context (or over full screen) and display the spinner only on LoadingViewController.

This way you can show the spinner over any view and dismiss it from another view. Some code below.

Create LoadingViewController and a delegate for it:

```
protocol LoadingViewControllerDelegate {
    func didFinishLoading(controller: LoadingViewController)
}

class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: LoadingViewControllerDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do your spinner code here
    }

    // Delegate function, should be fired when loading is done.
    func finished() {
        if self.delegate != nil {
            self.delegate?.didFinishLoading(self)
        }
    }
}
```

In your first ViewController, display the LoadingViewController:

```
let loading = LoadingViewController(nibName: "LoadingViewController", bundle: nil)
loading.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
loading.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
presentViewController(loading, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In your second ViewController, implement a method to receive the LoadingViewController:

```
var loading: LoadingViewController? = nil
```

Again in your first ViewController, send the data over to the second:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ViewC1Segue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        destination.loading = self.loading
    }
}
```

And now in your second ViewController, conform to `LoadingViewControllerDelegate` and set the delegate:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, LoadingViewControllerDelegate {
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        loading.delegate = self
    }
    ...
    // MARK: - LoadingViewControllerDelegate
    func didFinishLoading(controller: LoadingViewController) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And in your Alamofire call, run the following upon completion:

```
loading.finished()
```

Comment: I seem to be having a little trouble entering this. On this line: (segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController).loading = self.loading I get the error: Value of type 'SecondViewController' has no member 'loading' - I have added every bit of code throughout. :/ Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesG Edited that part, should work now. And also make sure that there is a `var loading: LoadingViewController? = nil` in your destination (second) view controller.